# TradingView Adjust for Timezone

Tags: pine-script

I recently wrote short script to highlight the equity market open and close, and I want to see this on futures charts (i.e ES1!).

```
study("Open & Close", overlay=true)
openColor = na(time(timeframe.period, "0930-1030")) ? na : color.green
closeColor = na(time(timeframe.period, "1500-1600")) ? na : color.red
bgcolor(openColor)
bgcolor(closeColor)
```

The problem is that the time range strings given (e.g "0930-1030") are still evaluated in eastern time, so 10:30-11:30 and 16:00-17:00 end up being highlighted instead.

How can I make TradingView aware of `syminfo.timezone`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`time` and `timenow` always return UTC time. You will need to use other built-ins to fetch time information in the exchange's timezone: `second, minute, hour, year, month, dayofmonth, dayofweek` and `timestamp()` for example:
https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Sessions_and_time_functions.html#built-in-variables-for-working-with-time

[EDIT: 2020.09.15 16:00 — LucF]

```
//@version=4
study("Open & Close", "", true)
zone = input("GMT-5")
c_bgOpen = input(color.green)
c_bgClose = input(color.red)
o1 = timestamp(zone, year, month, dayofmonth, 09, 30)
o2 = timestamp(zone, year, month, dayofmonth, 10, 30)
c1 = timestamp(zone, year, month, dayofmonth, 15, 00)
c2 = timestamp(zone, year, month, dayofmonth, 16, 00)
c_bg = time >= o1 and time <= o2 ? c_bgOpen : time >= c1 and time <= c2 ? c_bgClose  : na
bgcolor(c_bg)
```

[image]

Comment: I don't understand how to construct a time frame from these primitives.

Comment: Added an example.